# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError crash on some devices

Tags: android, android-ndk

I have a published application that is reporting a `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError` crash on some devices. To be more precise, the app crashes on start up with the following log message:

`Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load qcc: findLibrary returned null`

The actual crashing is in the `System.loadLibrary("qcc");` instruction, so the app is not finding the library for sure.

The problem is I haven't been able to reproduce the issue myself. Actually the same apk works perfectly on a lot of different devices and versions.

---

The app uses two C libraries written and compiled by a third person. They have been compiled using the `arm-linux-androideabi-4.6` toolchain, and I am integrating them in my project running `nkd-build` with the following `Android.mk` file:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := libqcc
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := qcc/libqcc.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := libqpe
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := qpe/libqpe.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

The error is being reported on different devices, but all of them at the moment are one of the following Android versions: 2.2, 2.2.1 or 2.2.2.

---

I think it could be either an architecture issue or a weird problem during installation.

Does anyone know what the problem could be?

---

**UPDATE:**

I realized that I could reproduce the problem in an Android 2.2 emulator. This is extra information that I could gather from the logcat.

```
11:14:59.962 I/dalvikvm(  287): Unable to dlopen(/data/data/.../lib/libqcc.so): Cannot load library: link_image[1995]: failed to link libqcc.so
11:14:59.962 W/dalvikvm(  287): Exception Ljava/lang/UnsatisfiedLinkError;
```

Comment: Could be armeabi vs. armeabi-v7a issue. Build for both, just in case.

Comment: Seva Alekseyev is right, maybe you can try to create an Application.mk file (if you don't have it yet) with this line: 
APP_ABI := armeabi armeabi-v7a

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this case the problem was that the library was using some C methods that are not supported on Android 2.2

This [link](http://mpigulski.blogspot.com.es/2010/09/debugging-dlopen-unsatisfiedlinkerror.html) was the way to discover the problem.

Methods such as `pthread_rwlock_init` are not implemented in the system's C library until Android 2.3 ([source](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=24228)).